# What's the song when Naruto talks to the little kid in episode 13?

Tags: naruto, music

What's the name of the soundtrack played in *Naruto* season 1 episode 13? It's played around 15:35 when Naruto talks to the little kid.

Answer (score 1):

It is a variation of the main theme slowed down. The closest I was able to find of the same would be [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b-VbuN0kLs).

Skip to  :50